# List Append Creates two-dimensional instead of one-dimensional List from Beautifulsoup.find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a website with beautifulsoup in python, and after finding all elements, I want to strip the digits from the result list and add them to a list:

```
## find all prices on page
prices = soup.find_all("div", class_="card-footer")
#print(prices)

## extract digits
stripped = [] # declare empty list
for p in prices:
    print(p.get_text(strip=True))
    stripped.append(re.findall(r'\d+', p.get_text(strip=True)))
print(stripped)
```

Result:

```
[['555'], ['590'], ['599'], ['1000'], ['5000'], ['5000'], ['9999'], ['10000'], ['12000']]
```

How do I have to do it, to end up with a one-dimensional list only?

Since I only need the "stripped" list, maybe there is also an easier way to extract digits other than using `re.findall` and do it directly in the line `prices = soup.find_all("div", class_="card-footer")`?

Thanks!

Comment: Change ``stripped.append(..)`` --> ``stripped.extend(..)``

Comment: Will have to try that solution as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find_all returns a list. Therefore, if you're only interested in the first element (there probably is only one in your case) then:

```
stripped.append(re.findall(r'\d+', p.get_text(strip=True))[0])
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks.